# La aplicación se encuentra en modo de interrupcion

Tags: wpf, binding

Estoy creando un buscaminas con WPF. Para ello he creado el tablero en una lista y lo muestro haciendo binding con itemsource. Hasta ayer me funcionaba y hoy me salta esta excepción (lo pongo en texto porque no me deja poner fotos) y no se que hacer. Soy nueva en esto, alguna sugerencia?

**La aplicación se encuentra en modo de interrupcion**
La aplicación entró en un estado de interrupción, pero no hay código para mostrar porque todos los subprocesos ejecutaban código externo (normalmente, código de sistema o de marco).
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Se produjo una excepción al agregar un valor a una colección de tipo 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection'.' (número de línea: '17'; posición de línea: '26').'
Excepcion interna:
InvalidOperationException: La operación no es válida mientras ItemsSource esté en uso. Obtenga acceso y modifique los elementos con ItemsControl.ItemsSource.

Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
[Código externo]

Mi **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View.Converters"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:View.Converters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <ItemsControl x:Name="boardView">
      
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                        <converters:SquareStatusConverter x:Name="squareStatusToEllipseFill">
                        </converters:SquareStatusConverter>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button>
                                   <!-- <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="{Binding Square.State, Converters={StaticResource SquareStatusConverter }">-->
                                        <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="{Binding Square.State}">
                                        </Ellipse> 
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Y **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            //--------------------------------------------
            InitializeComponent();
            var game = IGame.Parse(new List<string> {
                                  ".....",
                                  ".*...",
                                  ".....",
                                  "...*.",
                                  "**...",
                                });

            //uncover without mine
            var position = new Vector2D(2, 0);
            game = game.UncoverSquare(position);
            //uncover with mine
            var position2 = new Vector2D(1, 1);
            game = game.ToggleFlag(position2);
            //flagged square
            var position3 = new Vector2D(2, 2);
            game = game.ToggleFlag(position3);
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Square>> res = Rows(game.Board);
            boardView.ItemsSource = res;
        }

        // returns a List<Square> containing all squares on the rowth row of board.
        IEnumerable<Square> Row(IGameBoard board, int row)
        {
            // Querying width
            var width = board.Width;
             
            // Querying height
            var height = board.Height;

            var position = new Vector2D(row, 0);
            var square = board[position];

            // Querying square at position (0, 0)
            List<Square> a = new List<Square>();
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                position = new Vector2D(row, i);
                square = board[position];
                a.Add(square);
            } 
            
            return a;
        }

       IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Square>> Rows(IGameBoard board) {

            // Querying height
            var height = board.Height;

            List<IEnumerable<Square>> rows = new List<IEnumerable<Square>>();

            for (int i=0; i < height ; i++)
            { 
                IEnumerable <Square> a = Row(board, i);
                rows.Add(a);
            }
           
            return rows;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Gracias!!!